# PHP calculate total cash based on money income and outcome SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo, group-by, sum

I have a table like this

```
id | date | category | concept | amount
```

the category has 2 possible options: income and outcome

so, for example, my table can look something like this:

```
id | date       | category | concept        | amount
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 2020-01-20 | income   | tv sale        | 200
2  | 2020-01-20 | income   | radio sale     | 100
3  | 2020-01-20 | income   | pc sale        | 500
4  | 2020-01-25 | outcome  | salary payment | 600
```

Based on that table I need to make the following account: sum all the category items when the category is an income and subtract when the category is an outcome to give me a total of cash.

Basically 200+100+500-600 = 200

I want to show that result in the header of my pos, here is a screenshot to give an idea:

[image: what i want to do >]

How should I make the SQL consult in my PHP code? I'm using PDO here is the model code:

```
static public function mdlIngresarMovimiento($tabla, $datos){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(fecha, categoria_cd, concepto, observacion_cd, monto) VALUES (:fecha, :categoria_cd, :concepto, :observacion_cd, :monto)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":fecha", $datos["fecha"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":categoria_cd", $datos["categoria_cd"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":concepto", $datos["concepto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":observacion_cd", $datos["observacion_cd"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":monto", $datos["monto"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = null;

}
```

here is my controller:

```
static public function ctrCrearMovimiento(){

    if(isset($_POST["fechaMovimiento"])){

        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["categoriaMovimiento"]) &&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["entradaConcepto"]) &&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["observacionMovimiento"])){

            $tabla = "caja_diaria";

            $datos = array("id"=>$_POST["idMovimiento"],
                           "fecha"=>$_POST["fechaMovimiento"],                  
                           "categoria_cd"=>$_POST["categoriaMovimiento"],
                           "concepto"=>$_POST["entradaConcepto"],
                           "observacion_cd"=>$_POST["observacionMovimiento"],
                           "monto"=>$_POST["montoMovimiento"]);

            $respuesta = ModeloCajaDiaria::mdlIngresarMovimiento($tabla, $datos);

            if($respuesta == "ok"){

                echo'<script>

                swal({
                      type: "success",
                      title: "El movimiento ha sido guardado correctamente",
                      showConfirmButton: true,
                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                      }).then(function(result){
                                if (result.value) {

                                window.location = "caja-diaria";

                                }
                            })

                </script>';

            }else{

            echo'<script>

                swal({
                      type: "error",
                      title: "¡El movimiento no puede ir vacío!",
                      showConfirmButton: true,
                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                      }).then(function(result){
                        if (result.value) {

                        window.location = "caja-diaria";

                        }
                    })

            </script>';



        }

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the computation directly in SQL with a conditional sum:

```
select sum(case when category = 'income' then amount else -amount end) total_sales
from mytable
```

Comment: Should it be "as total_sales"? or total_sales directly

Comment: @Cristian: both syntaxs are OK in most databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SUM (CASE 
             WHEN category='income' THEN amount
             WHEN category='outocome' THEN -amount
    END) AS total_sales
FROM table
```